# Wordpress get navigation link string from language file

Tags: wordpress, navigation, translation

Good evening everyone,

I have been translating Surfarama theme into Russian and everything except navigation links on the bottom of post (next/previous) has been successfully translated.

In theme functions.php I found that it is hard coded into the theme (on line 601):

```
<?php previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-previous">%link</div>', '<span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&larr; Previous', 'Previous post link', 'surfarama' ) . '</span>' ); ?>
<?php next_post_link( '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>', '<span class="meta-nav">' . _x( 'Next &rarr;', 'Next post link', 'surfarama' ) . '</span>' ); ?>
```

How can I make `'&larr; Previous'` to be extracted from ru_RU.po file as other theme strings which are not hard coded?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem:

Replaced

```
_x( '&larr; Previous', 'Previous post link', 'surfarama' )
```

with

```
__('&larr; Previous', 'surfarama')
```

Now link is translated!

It was not translated because _x function second variable is a suggestion (for example it can be noun or verb), while __ function just makes string translatable. I also tried _e function (which echo'es translated string), but string somehow appeared before navigation, so I used __ instead. 
Hope that someone will find this information useful.